# Python pyodbc 'execute only'

Tags: python, pyodbc, readonly

I am trying out the pyodbc to connect to a local MSSQL database with the code bellow:

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
'Server=localhost;'
'Database=SampleDb;'
'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute = ('SELECT * FROM SampleDb.dbo.flights')

for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```

Getting the following error:

```
cursor.execute = ('SELECT * FROM SampleDb.dbo.flights')
AttributeError: 'pyodbc.Cursor' object attribute 'execute' is read-only
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cursor.execute` is a function, so you just need to call it and not to assign something to it. Try this:

```py
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM SampleDb.dbo.flights')
```

Sources:

- [pyodbc wiki](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor)